# Pivot and count simultaneously, pandas

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

Starting from a dataframe of the form

```
userId  | tag_id
----------------
12         2
34         2
44         2
43         2
12         5
44         5
43         5
12         8
43         8
34         8
34         8
...
```

How can I pivot this table such that each value of `tag_id` becomes a new column, the rows of the table are unique `userIDs` and the values on each `tag_id` column is the number of times that user appears with the corresponding tag. The end result, for the above case should be:

```
userId | 2 | 5 | 8 |
--------------------
12       1   1   1   
34       1   0   2
43       1   1   1
44       1   1   0
```

I have a rough idea on how pivoting works, but I can't figure out how to do the counts inside it.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.user_id,df.tag_id)` would do it

Comment: See question 9 of the linked answer.

Comment: @anky_91 that is perfect, would you mind writing this as an answer so I can accept it? Also, is there a way to avid getting a 2-level header?

Comment: @Qubix `pd.crosstab(df.user_id,df.tag_id).reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)` never mind, its a dupe. :)

Comment: @anky_91 oh, now I finally saw it's a dupe. Anyway, thank you so much for your answer. :)